# data.table join by subset NAs

Tags: r, data.table

This is a query that comes from an earlier thread I chanced upon, two tables DT1 and DT2

```
    DT1
  Country       State      City Start  End
1      IN   Telangana Hyderabad   100  200
2      IN Maharashtra      Pune   300  400
3      IN     Haryana   Gurgaon   500  600
4      IN Maharashtra      Pune   700  800
5      IN     Gujarat Ahmedabad   900 1000

DT2 with 7 rows
ID  No
1   157
2   346
3   389
4   453
5   562
6   9874
7   98745
```

When they are joined using this code,

```
DT2[DT1, on=.(No>Start,No<End), ]
```

produces this output, with 6 rows

```
   ID  No No.1 Country       State      City
1:  1 100  200      IN   Telangana Hyderabad
2:  2 300  400      IN Maharashtra      Pune
3:  3 300  400      IN Maharashtra      Pune
4:  5 500  600      IN     Haryana   Gurgaon
5: NA 700  800      IN Maharashtra      Pune
6: NA 900 1000      IN     Gujarat Ahmedabad
```

i can understand the NAs corresponding to IDs 6 and 7 (rownumbers 5 and 6), but why is the NA corresponding to ID 4 missing. 
ID4 which has 453 no, maps to no ranges in DT1 and should have thrown an NA?

EDIT1: Providing Code to create the datasets

```
DT1<-
structure(list(Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "IN", class = "factor"), 
    State = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Gujarat", 
    "Haryana", "Maharashtra", "Telangana"), class = "factor"), 
    City = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Ahmedabad", 
    "Gurgaon", "Hyderabad", "Pune"), class = "factor"), Start = c(100L, 
    300L, 500L, 700L, 900L), End = c(200L, 400L, 600L, 800L, 
    1000L)), .Names = c("Country", "State", "City", "Start", 
"End"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
DT2<-
structure(list(ID = 1:7, No = c(157L, 346L, 389L, 453L, 562L, 
9874L, 98745L)), .Names = c("ID", "No"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

> 

Comment: You should say what `Start` and `End` are set to.

Comment: You sure about your output?  Looks just like `DT1` again.

Comment: data provided initially was incorrect, have provided the right DT1 now

Comment: It would easier to help you if you actually provided the code to construct DT1 and DT2

Comment: The code for the datasets isn't giving me any rows, just the column names.

Comment: closing this, I figured out the logic. DT2[DT1,] does a subset of DT2, checking for values provided by DT1. it produces an NA only when DT1 related values are not seen in DT2.

Comment: Try the other way `setDT(DT1)[DT2, on = .(Start < No, End > No)]`